# github ACtion - Graphql not returning packages under organisation

Tags: github, graphql, github-actions

**I was using github action to delete and publish my private packages, it was working fine since last 1 and half year**

suddenly it start breaking because graphql not able to get all the packages under my organization

Hence i am not able to delete existing packages and further not able to publish new packages
Please guide me

Graphql query which I am using

```
query {
  organization(login: "#{ENV['INPUT_ORGANISATION-NAME']}") {
      packages(names: ["#{ENV['INPUT_PACKAGE-NAME']}"], first: 100){
        nodes{
          versions(last:100){
            nodes{
              id
              version
            }
          }
        }
      }
  }
}

It returning output like

data": {
    "organization": {
      "packages": {
        "nodes": []
      }
    }

Where i am expecting data like

current working directory /github/workspace
{
    :data => {
        :organization => {
            :packages => {
                :nodes => [
                    [0] {
                        :versions => {
                            :nodes => [
                                [0] {
                                         :id => "YYYYYYYYYY",
                                    :version => "0.1.0.qa"
                                },
                                [1] {
                                         :id => "XXXXXXXX",
                                    :version => "0.1.0.pre.production"
                                },
                                [2] {
                                         :id => "RRRRRRRRRRRR",
                                    :version => "0.1.0.demo"
                                },
                                [3] {
                                         :id => "@#@#@#@#!@@#",
                                    :version => "0.1.0.pre.demo"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

version to be deleted  0.1.0.qa
version object